# How can I change my script to consume only parts of a tweet?

Tags: json, mongodb, twitter, pymongo

I have a script consuming tweets into my local mongodb via pymongo:

```
import json
import pymongo
import tweepy

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()

        self.db = pymongo.MongoClient().test

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        self.db.tweets.insert(json.loads(tweet))

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        return True # Don't kill the stream


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(locations=[-74, 40, -73, 41])
```

At the moment, I get the full tweet, which is way more information than I actually need. How can I change the existing script so that I only consume the following information:

i)    Hashtag
ii)   UserID
iii)  PlaceID
iv)   timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

In `on_data`, parse the json to get the data you're interested in and save them:

```
def on_data(self, tweet):
    tweet_parsed = json.loads(tweet)
    if 'created_at' in tweet_parsed:
        hashtags = tweet_parsed['entities']['hashtags']
        for hashtag in hashtags:
            # Now get the hashtags.
            hashtag_text = hashtag['text']
        # Now get the user id.
        user_id = tweet_parsed['user']['id']
        # Now get the longitude.            
        longitude = tweet_parsed['coordinates']['coordinates'][0]
        # Now get the latitude.
        latiitude = tweet_parsed['coordinates']['coordinates'][1]
        # Now get the timestamp.
        timestamp = tweet_parsed['created_at']
```

Answer (score 0):

In `on_data`: instead of passing the original `tweet` object to `.insert`, create a new, local object with only the fields you want and copy the values from the tweet object.

Comment: How would I do that, do you have a link that describes the process or, alternatively, an update for the existing code? Sorry to be a drag but am still new to python and am finding the learning curve rather steep.